# select couple of random rows by different criteria in one query

Tags: mysql, random

I want to select 4 random rows from a table where level = 1 and 4 random rows from the same table where level=2. How can I do this in 1 query ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from (select * from your_table 
               where level = 1 order by rand() limit 4) x
union all
select * from (select * from your_table 
               where level = 2 order by rand() limit 4) y
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this...

```
SELECT product_id, title, description FROM products WHERE active = 1 AND stock > 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
```